# Stage: Not resizing to Scene

Tags: java, javafx

I have a scene on a stage. The width of the scene is 337.0 pixels. However, when I add it to the stage, the size of the stage is 337.6 pixels which leaves a white gap  at the right edge of the screen due to the 0.6 pixel difference.

I tried using `stage.sizeToScene()`, but that's not working. I also tried setting the  width of the stage manually by trying `stage.setWidth(337)`. that did not affect the width of the stage, it still remained 337.6.

The I tried the following: `stage.setWidth(337.0)`. Then when I print the stage width on the console, by using `stage.getWidth()`, the value printed is 337.0, however in actual, the 0.6 pixel white line still stays.

I tried doing the following alos:

```
stage.hide();
stage.show();
```

This worked, it removed the white line, but it shows the window switching which looks very bad. Is there a way to do the same without switching windows like above.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: don't manually size/position the nodes, instead use a layout that does so automatically (AnchorPane is not really useful here) - I suspect that there's a slight sizing mismatch between the two forms.

Comment: Yes, But I have also seen this issue occurring with other layouts I had used earlier. This issue also happened in Swing framework, but I never got any answer to it.

Comment: Ok, I found out something, please refer the edit in my question

Comment: hmm .. could be an issue with rounding/initial stage sizes: faintly remember (don't have the id handy, sry) there's a recently fixed issue. What you see might be a left-over ..

Comment: And what happens is when I switch back to the sign up scene, the size is what I mentioned, 337, but initially it had became 337.6.

Comment: I found a solution that we can use stage.hide() and then we do stage.show(), but this results in window switching which looks awful

Comment: Ok, now I edited the entire question after researching for an entire day. Please check it our.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with setting the correct size for my stage.

What helped in my case was using:

```java
stage.setMinWidth(newActiveScene.getRoot().minWidth(-1));
stage.setMinHeight(newActiveScene.getRoot().minHeight(-1));
```

where `stage` is the stage you are using and `newActiveScene` is your new scene set on the stage.

Actually I am using a method to set new Scenes on a Stage that looks like that:

```
/**
 * Sets a new active {@link Scene} on the stage.
 *
 * @param newActiveScene the new scene to show
 */
public static void setActiveScene(Scene newActiveScene) {
    stage.setScene(newActiveScene);
    stage.setMinWidth(newActiveScene.getRoot().minWidth(-1));
    stage.setMinHeight(newActiveScene.getRoot().minHeight(-1));
}
```

where `stage` is the used Stage. This assumes that `stage.show()` was already called once (for example when initializing the stage).

Comment: I'm sorry your code did not work, but when I replace setMinWidth and setMinHeight, with setWidth and setHeight, it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @wollsi, I would like to make some edits to his code. This is what worked well for me:

```
    public void setActiveScene(Scene newActiveScene) {
        stage.setScene(newActiveScene);
        stage.setWidth(newActiveScene.getRoot().minWidth(-1));
        stage.setHeight(newActiveScene.getRoot().minHeight(-1));
    }
```